# Achieving the same font size in different screens ratio

Tags: android, screen, screen-resolution

I'm using a library in Android that with a given size, it creates dynamically a font.

Before, I used to calculate the font sizes taking as a reference the width of the screen so it was always using percents of the width, using the following formula: x/100*screenWidth

What happens with this? That if the screen has a different ratio (relation between width and height) this solution is not accurated because it will adapt to the width but not to the height...

I'm a bit lost trying to find a solution for a new formula that take into account both width and height. Any idea? Really thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a percentage of (screenWidth + screenHeight)/2 ?

Comment: The advantage is it takes into account both height and width, but I agree it is gross. Maybe include the ratio (width/height) and you'll find a formula that suits better. BTW, you might need to handle orientation changes or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is a difficult problem that i faced on per application. I can not find any easy solution so i am trying to use different layout files. For example Nexus-7 uses layout-large-port & layout-large-land & layout-large. So i am designing different layout files. It is very painful but it shows good performance. If there is another way to solve this problem, i want to know this. Finally i meant with layout files that on the resources class we have a default layout file for our xml files. You can add new layout files for different sizes. I hope i was clear and you understand me.
Also check this link [Screen Supports](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I'm developing a videogame, so I'm not using layout or anything like that. I just wanted to know a mathematical formula with both sides... but apparently there is not.

Comment: There are a lot of screen sizes like 1920x1080, 1280x800, 800x480 and so like that. We can say that you can not use a general formula for all screen sizes. Because of different width/height ratios.